# iOS copy multiple images to pasteboard

Tags: ios, image, copy, pasteboard

I can copy one image to the pasteboard like so:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard;
pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
UIImage *image;
[pasteboard setImage:image];
```

How can I copy two or three images to the pasteboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setImages:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstImage, secondImage, nil]];
```

I think this is all you're looking for.  It is also possible to set a single image with multiple types (PNG, JPG, etc.) so that it is more likely that another application will find a usable image.

~ Good Luck

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response! long weekend! But this is just what I'm looking for! Thanks!