# Select multiple images in Mobile Safari 7 using javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I would like to programmatically select multiple images which the user would then be able to copy and paste into other apps (such as Messages).

It does seem to be possible to [copy multiple images in native apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864775/ios-copy-multiple-images-to-pasteboard), however I can't seem to find anything as to whether or not this is possible using any APIs available from JS in Mobile Safari.